# Getting "Access denied for user..." every 2nd hit

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, dapper, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to use dapper with mysql in .net core 1.0. I'm using this mysql connector: https://github.com/bgrainger/MySqlConnector

I know the connector is in alpha but I was wondering if anyone had a similar issue when using it together with dapper.

This is my simple model:

```
        public List<GeneralModel> GetAllLists()
        {
            try
            {
                using (DbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=lists;Uid=Unnamed;Pwd=lol;"))
                {
                    return connection.Query<GeneralModel>("SELECT * FROM lists.general").ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And this is the controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        GeneralModel GenRepo = new GeneralModel();
        return View(GenRepo.GetAllLists());
    }
```

When I go to the index page for the first time, it works. If I refresh, I get an "Access denied for user...". I have no idea what could be causing the error. I don't think the problem is in my code.

Edit:

I guess the problem is in the connector, since this also returns the error after a refresh:

```
            List<GeneralModel> lists = new List<GeneralModel>();
            using (DbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=lists;Uid=Unnamed;Pwd=lol;"))
            {
                using (DbCommand myCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM lists.general";

                    connection.Open();
                    using (DbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {
                            GeneralModel tmpGen = new GeneralModel();
                            tmpGen.name = myReader["name"].ToString();
                            tmpGen.description = myReader["description"].ToString();
                            tmpGen.language = myReader["language "].ToString();

                            lists.Add(tmpGen);
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            return lists;
```

Comment: side note: there's no point doing a `catch` that just re-throws (`throw`); but back to the main point: wow, I'm amazed that is behaving oddly - I'm pleasantly surprised to see correct use of `using` etc, and there's nothing in there that looks odd. This might sound a bit like finger-pointing, but I wonder if the real issue here is in the mysql provider. Is there any way you could try doing the same thing long-hand in ADO.NET (old-school style), and see if it still breaks? - bonus final point: try using `.AsList()` instead of `.ToList()` - if the input is already buffered it's slightly cheaper.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for the tips! It does looks like the problem is in the provider. Too bad because I really wanted to try .net core, but without mysql support, it's a no go as this is the only mysql provider for .net core 1.0 as far as I know.

Comment: One part of me is greatly relieved that it wasn't my fault; another part of me shares your frustration. You should feed this back as a report, but the url suggests this isn't the official branch, so I don't know how much time it will get (could be fixed instantly, could be fixed never)

Comment: (very minor, but `"description "` with the space could cause problems)

Comment: I’ve created a GitHub issue for further investigation: https://github.com/bgrainger/MySqlConnector/issues/28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was caused by [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/bgrainger/MySqlConnector) not correctly handling the fast path for a [`COM_CHANGE_USER` packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-change-user.html).

MySQL Server (versions 5.6 and 5.7) doesn't appear to immediately accept the user's credentials, but always returns an [Authentication Method Switch Request Packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::AuthSwitchRequest). MariaDB (which you are using) does implement the fast path and immediately returns an OK packet.

The connector has now been updated to handle this response and should stop throwing the spurious "Access Denied" exceptions. The [fix](https://github.com/bgrainger/MySqlConnector/commit/b0c5be49c82b59289926cb13d3d482e4bcf4eee4) is in [0.1.0-alpha09](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/0.1.0-alpha09).